# SQL Server Assemblies and SQLBinary DataType

Tags: c#, sql-server, assemblies, types, varbinary

I have a c# assembly which takes in a SQLBinary variable to decrypt...

```
[SqlProcedure(Name="Decrypt")]
public static SqlInt32 Decrypt(SqlBinary toDecrypt)
{
    return runQuery(toDecrypt);
}

// decrypt or encrypt is determined based on the datatype of argValue
private static SqlInt32 runQuery(object argValue)
{
    // create connection and command

       command.Parameters.Add("@argValue", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 1024).Value = (SqlBinary)argValue;
```

I include the (SqlBinary)argValue as a column in the select statement for simple debugging. It doesnt appear as if this SqlBinary value is properly being placed into the query.

argValue is being used like so:

```
QueryString += "SELECT decryptbykey(@argValue);";
```

Whats being returned looks like a truncated version of (SqlBinary)argValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my own question:

I had to cast the result of decryptbykey to a varchar ... duh! :)